# Posting to Facebook Page using GraphAPI

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am attempting to use the Facebook Graph API.  My "App" will execute as a command line script on a Linux server.  As part of the server side application, I am specifying the User Access Token of a user that is the owner of the page to which I am attempting to publish, then obtaining a Page Access Token for the specific page I want to post to.

When the Facebook App is in "Developer Mode" I am able to obtain a User Access Token containing "publish_pages" permissions, and everything works as expected, except noone but me can see the resulting posts.  When a post is submitted in this manner, and then I switch the app to "Public Mode", everyone can see what was posted previously.

The problem comes when attempting to post again while the app is in "Public Mode".  At that point, I receive an error saying that the application "Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permissions".  When I go back and attempt to reinitialize my User Access Token, manage_pages is an option but publish_actions is not.

While my App is in "Public Mode", there is nothing I can do to programmatically post a message to the page, which the user associated with the app is the Admin of.

Has anyone found an effective way to do this?  Or am I doomed to have to use a third party service for this capability?

Answer (score 0):

Currently on August 1, Facebook seems to have made the situation worse as I get "(#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission" when in *development mode*. They seemed to have changed things **yet again** today.

Here is what the change seems to have been: "The publish_actions permission has been removed. Apps that have already been approved for publish_actions can continue using the permission until August 1st, 2018. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook and Instagram beyond this date, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead
" at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes

Comment: Yeah, it seems that automated posting is now disabled. FB wants an actual person to click an actual button.